# Hiding Hyperlink on mouse hovering in MVC project

Tags: css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have designed a MVC application.But I get the url while hovering my mouse on the links.Please suggest how not to show the url link."Department" is the name of my controller and "Finance" is my ActionResult at the controller page.

```
    @Html.ActionLink("Finance & Accounting","Finance","Department")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add the title attribute to show some *other* text e.g.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Finance & Accounting", "Finance", "Department", null, new { title = "Finance & Accounting" })
```